Answering a scanf() within the program
I am trying to program a C Crash course for students in VPL. The students write a program in a file and I try to compile it with a another file I wrote to grade the program the students wrote.
The concrete task is to write a quiz (printing a random math question like 2+2 and the user is supposed to answer it). My goal is to grade it by testing it, so my program needs to provide an input to the scanf.
I've thought about using fprintf(stdin,...), but I've seen that it doesn't work because stdin is supposed to read from the console, not write to it.

You could use the popen function which allows you to write into another application's stdin stream, and read from their stdout.

Are you sure you don't just want some kind of shell script?

Maybe just redirect from a file: your_program < input.txt.

If you need the program to behave as if the input was typed at a terminal, you probably need to look at running it using a "pseudo-tty" or "pty".  However, setting those up is non-trivial (though far from impossible).  With a pty, you'd be able to read the output from the program as well as writing to its input.  Tracking standard error separately probably presents some problems.  The tag [tag:pty] can be used to search for questions about pseudo-ttys on SO (so enter "[c] [pty]" in the search bar; searching for "[c] pseudo-tty" also produces results).

@OldBoy Is there a way to call popen() for a specific function or do I have to write a file to call the method in its main?

No, you cannot call functions of an executable unless you write your own debugger. You can  only use popen to interact with its console interface.


my program needs to provide an input to the scanf.

Use stdin = freopen("inputfile.txt", "r", stdin);, then call student's code.
